# We know an example iff any exist

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Consider a statement of this form:

> We don't know whether or not there exist any [X] with property [Y], but we do know that [some concrete instance/example of an X] has property [Y] iff any [X] has property [Y].

Is there a name for this sort of statement? When is it possible to (truthfully) make such a statement? Where have such statements appeared in math?

(The one statement I've heard that inspired this question is that we have a (completely impractical) algorithm that will solve any problem in NP, and we know that it will run in polynomial time iff P=NP.)

I also realize this is similar to [Unique candidate that fails](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4351/12859), except that we'd know of a unique candidate but not know whether or not it fails.

Comment: Something like this might be called a "universal object" for property $Y$ in category theory. I don't believe the statement that inspired your question: can you give a reference for it, please.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't remember where I saw it in the first place, but [here it is on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=P_versus_NP_problem&oldid=869628008#Polynomial-time_algorithms).

Comment: Thanks for the link. You haven't stated it quite right: those algorithms solve particular NP-complete problems in a certain sense (and so they can be used to solve any other given NP-complete problem in that sense when composed with an appropriate reduction). Sorry if I sound a bit pedantic - I was just interested in the actual statement.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you formally express the above statement using the language of predicate logic, e.g $\exists x: Y(x)$, etc.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think $(\exists x : Y(x)) \implies Y(a)$ (where $a$ is some constant) is how I'd express that like that.

Comment: This would be true only if the domain of discourse was empty or $\{ a \}$.